# My app does not have a similar app in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I published a game in Google play around 3 weeks ago, I thought google pick some other game and put them in similar app section, but apparently it is not how it works. What should I do in order to have some similar game in Google market?

Link to game.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.colortivity.amirali.colortivity

Answer (score 2):

I believe there will be many factors behind the similar apps suggestion. Its best to wait for atleast a month or two.

Comment: Thanks for the respond Ashwin